# Javascript GetElementsByClassName Not Working

Tags: javascript

Okay, so here is my Javascript code in which I cannot troubleshoot why this is not working. Basically, I will have multiple drop-down menus all with the class of 'dropdown' and I want to change a particular dropdown (show contents of the division) when an image is clicked. I have already confirmed that the Javascript **is properly** linked to the JS and CSS files. I have also confirmed that the onClick methos is working properly for the image buttons that control the dropdown menus. When the image is clicked, it will send a parameter to a function that regulates the drop down. Here is the JS:

```
    var current;
    var get = function(name) {
        current = document.getElementsByClassName(name);
    }
    var show = function(menu) {
        get('image');
        if(current[menu].src === 'plus.png') {
            current[menu].src = 'minus.png';
            get('dropdown');
            current[menu].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            current[menu].src = 'plus.png';
            get('dropdown');
            current[menu].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

**Edit** Here is the full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Gwiddle - Site Creator</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='banner'><p>Gwiddle Site Creator</p></div>
        <div class='center'>
            <p>Tools<img src='plus.png' class='image' onClick='show(0)' /></p>
            <p>Options<img class='image' src='plus.png' onClick='show(1)' /></p>
            <p>Code<img class='image' src='plus.png' onClick='show(2)' /></p>
        </div>
        <div class='dropdown'>
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
    font-family:Verdana;
}
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
img {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:.3em;
    width:.8em;
    height:.8em;
}
.center {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.center > p {
    font-size:1.4em;
}
.dropdown {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    margin:1em 0 1em 0;
}
#banner {
    font-size:2em;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#3399FF;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px 2px #CCCCCC;
    padding:.5em 0 .5em 0;
}
#banner p {
    margin:0;
}
#tools {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: You need to debug. What logging have you done? Did you log the value of `current[menu].src`? I'd imagine it's giving you the fully qualified URL instead of just the local path. Are you getting console errors? Did you log the actual collection returned?

Comment: ...and if you're just trying to select the `img` that was clicked, then all you need to do is pass `this`, and that'll be a reference to the image. `onClick='show(this)'`

Comment: Change `current[menu].src === 'plus.png'` to `current[menu].src.endsWith('plus.png')`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a _collection_ of elements, even if there's just one element with a given classname. Not sure what you want to achieve by trying to access its elements by some arbitrary key anyway.

Comment: Trying to alert the value of current[menu].src gives me an undefined

Comment: endsWith made no difference. And raina, I know it is a collection which is why I used [menu] to select a particular one (in this case 0 is passed as the parameter)

Comment: Actually, if I do alert(document.getElementsByClassName('image')) I get [objects HTML Collection] but if I add on [0].src nothing works

Comment: @turkey3 Then you're doing something wrong, because it is working. You shouldn't forget, that you have to click twice before `Test` disappears the first time.

Comment: @turkey3 you wrote `current[menu][0].src`? Why do you think that should work?

Comment: I did not write [menu][0]

Comment: Here's what I am doing, please listen. I commented out ALL my code. If I do this console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('image'); I get <HTML Collection... if I do this: console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].src); I get an error in the log saying an undefined typeError

Comment: @turkey3 that is not a problem of that log command, it is a problem of my suggested change. Chrome cries about that (it is working in FF). You could use `current[menu].getAttribute('src') == 'plus.png'` instead. That should work better.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Firefox. I commented out all code and did this alert(document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].getAttribute('src')); to see what I would get and nothing. If I take out the [0].getAttribute('src') then I get [object HTMLCollection] so it clearly recognizes there are objects but cannot seem to change its property. Also, I am using the latest version of Firefox on Ubuntu.

Comment: You're keeping the HTML part in, right? Even this command works correctly at my FF. You can also keep the whole code, just add that alert to the beginning of the `show` function.

Comment: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/r7mt29rd/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/r7mt29rd/) (using `match` instead of `endsWith` for better compatibility)

Comment: I added my full HTML, CSS, and JS file if that helps. Look at my post above for the full files

Comment: Can you use those exact files and see if it works or try to tweak the JS so it does? That would mean a lot to me :)

Comment: Match works! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain to me how the match function works? I don't get those slashes

Comment: `current[menu].style.display = 'block';` can't work correctly if you use the `dropdown` class once but the `image` class several times. You can't use the value of `menu` in this case.

Comment: @turkey3: It's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), the slashes are the delimiters for the expression, the backslash escapes the dot(dot's have a special meaning in RegExp) the $ marks the end of the expression. It does exactly the same as the endsWith-suggestion, but is also supported by IE and older  browsers(I guess it's supported by each browser that supports Javascript). Demo for your updated code:  http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/r7mt29rd/2/

Answer (score 0):

This script works fine for me in Chrome 37 *with the script in the page*. It might not be supported in your browser
[GetElementsByClassName Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname).

You could try using [jquery](http://jquery.com):
`$('.image')[menu] ...`

Since you stated that it shouldn't be your browser, are you sure that the page can find that javascript file? Does an `alert('test');` get called if added to the script?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using latest Firefox on Ubuntu and have used it before just fine.